# Webpack ( Erro: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND)

Tags: javascript

estou com dificuldades para resolver o seguinte erro no Webpack: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND , tipo o script funciona corretamente conforme a saída abaixo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mas quando eu tento visualizar no console do Chrome, apresenta o seguinte erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Seguem as configurações que eu fiz aqui:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Muito obrigado pela atenção e ajuda :)

Comment: O erro diz arquivo não encontrado, então o problema deve estar no path, o mais comum é esquecer que (./) está no diretório atual, porém o correto seria um diretório anterior (../).

Answer (score 0):

Use um servidor web (pode ser um serviço no seu computador, não precisa ser remoto). O acesso pelo protocolo file:/// que você está usando tem uma série de restrições. Você precisa acessar via http ou https, e para isso tem de usar um servidor web.

Comment: e como eu faço isso?

Comment: Como você já usa webpack, talvez o caminho mais simples seja isto: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/